# How to switch Void Linux to "linux-lts" kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, void-linux, lts

I already installed the "linux-lts" and "linux-lts-headers" but can't see it as an option to pick up in Grub login screen. Yes I've visited the page: https://docs.voidlinux.org/config/kernel.html And already run "sudo xbps-reconfigure linux-lts" in a terminal.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: did you do `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: Yes I did. When I run ( xbps-query --regex -Rs '^linux[0-9.]+-[0-9._]+' ) I see that I have installed three kernel versions: 1- linux5.10-5.10.111_1 Linux kernel and modules (5.10 series)
2- linux5.13-5.13.19_1  Linux kernel and modules (5.13 series)
3- linux5.15-5.15.34_1  Linux kernel and modules (5.15 series)

Comment: what steps exactly do you take in Grub? What options do you get?

Comment: And, when I run ( xbps-query -Rs linux-lts* ) I get the result I that I already installed the : 1- ( linux-lts-5.10_1 ) 2- ( linux-lts-headers-5.10_1 )

Comment: I get this: https://ibb.co/7YjC2Dh

Comment: I mean why I don't see the "linux-lts" option there? or the one named " linux5.10-5.10.111_1" is the LTS kernel one? Actually I am new in Void linux.

Comment: it appears that the LTS kernel *is* the 5.10 kernel. `linux-lts` is just the name of the package that installs a specific kernel (the 5.10 kernel in this case)

Comment: Then, the problem has been solved. Have a good day. Best wishes. Thank you.